# When to use files to store data rather than a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am thinking when to use files instead of a database table for storage of data?

Example if you just have some backend settings, you could store them in a file..

Or is it best practise to have everthing in a DB?

I am using Rails as framework for my web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to set some settings to be used in an app, why not just create a config or initializer file?

Comment: I have about 50 columns (Prices) I need to store, properly best to store them in DB and for file paths, etc. other variables I would store them in a YAML configration file.

Comment: If they are hard coded values that are not going to change throughout the life of the app, you can set them in a YAML, config, or initializer file, but if they are going to change, it might be best to put them in a db so that you don't have to restart your server to have the values take effect.